# Moving a row in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

How can one move a row in `jTable` so that **row1** goes to **row2**'s position and **row2** goes to **row1**'s position ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `moveRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

Or, if you aren't using the DefaultTableModel then implement a simliar method in your custom model.

Comment: I didn't notice that there was a link. it's been helpful. thanks.

Comment: The example link has been removed. You will now need to read the API for the proper syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my code that I've just developed using the answer in this question.
With those function you can select multiple rows at a time and move them down or up in a `JTable`. I've attached those function to `JButton`, but i clean them out to make them more readable.

The last code line of both method (`setRowSelectionInterval()`) is used to follow the selection on the row being moved, since `moveRow()` doesn't move the selection but the content of the row.

```
public void moveUpwards()
{
    moveRowBy(-1);
}

public void moveDownwards()
{
    moveRowBy(1);
}

private void moveRowBy(int by)
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
    int destination = rows[0] + by;
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();

    if (destination < 0 || destination >= rowCount)
    {
        return;
    }

    model.moveRow(rows[0], rows[rows.length - 1], destination);
    table.setRowSelectionInterval(rows[0] + by, rows[rows.length - 1] + by);
}
```

Comment: Have a JTextAreaEditor in one jTable cell. It moves the row, but without the text in the JTextAreaEditor. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Solved it with zed's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517416/8311151

Answer (score 1):

```
TableModel model = jTable.getModel();
for(int col=0; col<model.getColumnCount(); col++) {
  Object o1 = model.getValueAt(row1, col);
  Object o2 = model.getValueAt(row2, col);
  model.setValueAt(o1, row2, col);
  model.setValueAt(o2, row1, col);
}
```